# How to dynamically create and append to a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container `#form_wrapper` and I want to dynamically add inputs from an array `rf_fields`. Assume the value of the array is `var rf_fields = ['input1...','input2...'];`

```
  for(field in rf_fields){
    $('#form_wrapper').append( '<div class"form_question"></div>' );
    $('.form_question').append( '<div class"title"></div>' )    
                       .append( '<div class"question"></div>' )    
                       .append( $('<input>').attr( rf_fields[ field ]) )
                       .append( '<div class"eg"></div>' );
  }
```

The output I get is:

```
<div id="form_wrapper">
  <div class"form_question"></div>
  <div class"form_question"></div>
</div>
```

The output I intend to get is:

```
<div id="form_wrapper">

  <div class"form_question">
    <div class"title"> ... </div>
    <div class"question"> ... </div>
       --input--
    <div class"eg"> ... </div>
  </div>

  <div class"form_question">
    <div class"title"> ... </div>
    <div class"question"> ... </div>
       --input--
    <div class"eg"> ... </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have `class"form_question"` and not `class="form_question"`?

Comment: You really should consider to use templates. For example [{{ moustache }}](https://mustache.github.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `=` at appropriate places, and the code will work.

```
$('#form_wrapper').append( '<div class="form_question"></div>' );
$('.form_question').append( '<div class="title"></div>' )    
                   .append( '<div class="question"></div>' )    
                   .append( $('<input>').attr( rf_fields[ field ]) )
                   .append( '<div class="eg"></div>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the necessary `=`'s for attributes. You also need to ensure you append to the newly created element, else it will fail after the first loop.

```
for(field in rf_fields){
    $('<div class="form_question"></div>')
        .append( '<div class="title"></div>' )    
        .append( '<div class="question"></div>' )    
        .append( $('<input>').attr( rf_fields[ field ]) )
        .append( '<div class="eg"></div>' )
        .appendTo($('#form_wrapper'));
}
```